# Python won't break from a while True

Tags: python

this is my code but as the title says I can not break and if I put something outside the while True and lives go below 0 nothing happens.

```
from random import randint
    import sys
    value = int(randint(1,10))
    lives = int(5)
    userinp = int(0)
    if lives == 0:
        print("no lives :(")
    while True:
        if lives != 0:
            print(value)
            print("You currently have: ", lives, " lives left")
            userinp = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 10: ")
            if int(userinp) == int(value):
                print("Well done you wn :D")
                sys.exit()
            elif int(userinp) > int(value):
                print("Your guess was too high please guess again")
                lives = lives - 1
            elif int(userinp) < int(value):
                print("Your guess was too low please guess again")
                lives = lives - 1
    if lives == 0:
        print("this")
```

Comment: Where *is* your `break`?

Comment: `lives = int(5) ; userinp = int(0)` Why?

Comment: A `while True` is an infinite loop, consuming 100% of all CPU cycles and will never break - since a `while <condition>` only ends when the condition becomes `False`, but that can never be, because it is always `True`!

Answer (score 2):

Your loop essentially looks like:

```
while True:
    if lives != 0:
        # do stuff with lives
```

This is an infinite loop. The loop wont break even if `lives == 0`, because this condition is tested as part of the loop block, not as the loop condition.
You should simply do :

```
while lives != 0:
    # do stuff with lives
```

Or even `while lives > 0:` in case you manage to loose several lives during 1 loop iteration (doesn't seem to be possible here but better safe than sorry).

And since you seem to want to learn Python, there are a few other things you may want to learn and improve also:

No need to convert integers to integers here:

```
value = int(randint(1,10))
lives = int(5)
userinp = int(0)
```

Numbers like `5` and `0`, and `randint(1,10)` are integers by themselves. `"5"` and `"0"` are strings containing a number as single character and would need to be converted before being compared to integers, but it is not needed here. randint() returns integers.

This is dead code since you have set  `lives` to `5` 2 lines above and not modified it afterwards:

```
if lives == 0:
    print("no lives :(")
```

You should check if the user actually inputs a valid integer convertible value instead of an arbitrary string: (`continue` will skip to the next loop iteration, so it will ask the user for input again without decrementing `lives`

```
userinp = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 10: ")
if not userinp.isnumeric(): continue
```

No need to convert your already integer `value` to an integer again and again and AGAIN:

```
if int(userinp) == int(value):

elif int(userinp) > int(value):

elif int(userinp) < int(value):
```

Avoid using `sys.exit()`, you may just `break` instead (to get out of the loop and continue.

And finally, Python has handy `-=, +=, *=, /=` operators, so you can write `lives -= 1` instead of `lives = lives - 1`

Answer (score 1):

A `while True` is an infinite loop, consuming 100% of all CPU cycles and will never break - since a `while <condition>` only ends when the condition becomes `False`, but that can never be, because it is always `True`!

Try not fighting the nature of your loop:

```
while True:
    if lives != 0:
        print(value)
        print("You currently have: ", lives, " lives left")
        userinp = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 10: ")
        if int(userinp) == int(value):
            print("Well done you wn :D")
            sys.exit()
        elif int(userinp) > int(value):
            print("Your guess was too high please guess again")
            lives = lives - 1
        elif int(userinp) < int(value):
            print("Your guess was too low please guess again")
            lives = lives - 1
    if lives == 0:  # indent condition to fall within the loop
        print("this")
    if lives < 0:  # add an extra case to handle what you want
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to break the `while` when `lives == 0`, either by a `break` or by changing the while condition.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution, you can set the `break` condition specifically to end your while loop if a specific event occurs.

```
while lives > 0:
    print(value)
    print("You currently have: ", lives, " lives left")
    userinp = input("Please enter a number from 1 to 10: ")
    if int(userinp) == int(value):
        print("Well done you wn :D")
        sys.exit()
    elif int(userinp) > int(value):
        print("Your guess was too high please guess again")
        lives = lives - 1
    elif int(userinp) < int(value):
        print("Your guess was too low please guess again")
        lives = lives - 1


print("this")
```